# VS Code terminal 'Flutter failed to write to a file at "C:\flutter\version".'

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
Flutter failed to write to a file at "C:\flutter\version". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory. Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.
```

This is the message I get every time I try to run the flutter command on VS Code's terminal. I don't know how to solve this problem. This question could be a duplicate, but I still prefer to ask a new question, since old questions are unlikely to be still updated and/or seen.

EDIT: The file was moved from the C: drive to the A: drive. I don't know why that would make a difference. If you (hypothetical viewer from the future) don't have a different drive, I don't know how to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is due to your Flutter folder being in the C: drive as C: drive requires elevated permissions. I would suggest moving it some other drive and update the PATH, then try again.

Comment: And in which other folder should I put it?

Comment: You can put it in some other drive and try